# Not able to reverse the jQuery effect

Tags: jquery

Hello I need help this script is working as I wnated

```
jQuery('[href*="#'+divone+'"]').find("span").removeClass("fa fa-plus").addClass("fa fa-minus");
```

but after this I want VICE- VERSA on one click works above on another click replace class I Have tried toggleClass also not worked 
please help

```
<div class="wpsm_panel wpsm_panel-default">
  <div class="wpsm_panel-heading" role="tab">
    <h4 class="wpsm_panel-title">
      <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="" href="#ac_155_collapse6" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="ac_open_cl_icon fa-minus fa"></span>
        <span class="ac_title_class fa-minus fa">
          <span style="margin-right:6px;" class="fa-minus fa"></span>
          <span style="margin-right:6px;" class="fa-minus fa"></span>
          <p>this is the question?</p>
          <p></p>
        </span>
      </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="ac_155_collapse6" class="wpsm_panel-collapse collapse" style="display: block; height: 0px;" aria-expanded="false">
    <div class="wpsm_panel-body">this is answer </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`toggleClass()` does exactly what you need and should work fine:

```js
var divone = 'ac_155_collapse6';

jQuery('[href*="#' + divone + '"]').find("span").toggleClass("fa-plus fa-minus");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div class="wpsm_panel wpsm_panel-default">
  <div class="wpsm_panel-heading" role="tab">
    <h4 class="wpsm_panel-title">
      <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="" href="#ac_155_collapse6" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="ac_open_cl_icon fa-minus fa"></span>
        <span class="ac_title_class fa-minus fa">
          <span style="margin-right:6px;" class="fa-minus fa"></span>
        <span style="margin-right:6px;" class="fa-minus fa"></span>
        <p>this is the question?</p>
        <p></p>
        </span>
      </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="ac_155_collapse6" class="wpsm_panel-collapse collapse" style="display: block; height: 0px;" aria-expanded="false">
    <div class="wpsm_panel-body">this is answer </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that you don't need to include `.fa` in the list as you're just removing it, then adding it back again in your original code.

Comment: it doesnot replace my icon as my add and remove script does

Comment: In which case please show a more complete sample of your HTML and JS as this should work fine.

Comment: It does not replace icon. It replaces class associated with DOM element. That answers you question. Why icon is not showing was not in question, besides as RoryMcCrossan said, show your code if you want anyone to help further.

Comment: @Ghugu the code works absolutely fine. I placed your HTML in a snippet in my answer. If it doesn't work for you please check the console for errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global js var there, that changes from two values each time user clicks on the element. That way, you can tell which case you have to run, and exchange the classes on the element. Something like this:

```
var classFlag = 0;
$('...').click(function() {
    if (classFlag == 0) {
        jQuery('[href*="#'+divone+'"]').find("span").removeClass("fa fa-plus").addClass("fa fa-minus");
        classFlag = 1;
    }
    else {
        jQuery('[href*="#'+divone+'"]').find("span").removeClass("fa fa-minus").addClass("fa fa-plus");
        classFlag = 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: it stop my click effect

Comment: Maybe the flag initial value and the classes are the other way around. Try changing the first "if" to " == 1"

Comment: click still not work also it close my faq in second click please help

Comment: Try commenting the content on the if... else... i posted, and replace them with alerts, to debug easily if the click it's working. If those alerts work, maybe the issue is within the line with the remove and and classes methods.

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle, @Ghugu: https://jsfiddle.net/zze0vsoe/. The click works without a problem.

Comment: alert on click is working but it doesn't scroll to that faq as it is going before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163866/discussion-between-ignacio-tellez-and-ghugu).